# Plot showing but also giving an error: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'pyplot'

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, attributeerror

I am trying to use matplotlib.pyplot for simple plotting tasks. Somehow I get my plot as well as an error (see below). I have reinstalled matplotlib many times. Nothing so far has worked.

```
`AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[29], line 3
      1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      2 plt.plot([1,2])
----> 3 plt.show()

File ~\anaconda3\envs\music\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py:446, in show(*args, **kwargs)
    402 """
    403 Display all open figures.
    404 
   (...)
    443 explicitly there.
    444 """
    445 _warn_if_gui_out_of_main_thread()
--> 446 return _get_backend_mod().show(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\music\lib\site-packages\matplotlib_inline\backend_inline.py:99, in show(close, block)
     96 # only call close('all') if any to close
     97 # close triggers gc.collect, which can be slow
     98 if close and Gcf.get_all_fig_managers():
---> 99     matplotlib.pyplot.close('all')

File ~\anaconda3\envs\music\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\_api\__init__.py:226, in caching_module_getattr.<locals>.__getattr__(name)
    224 if name in props:
    225     return props[name].__get__(instance)
--> 226 raise AttributeError(
    227     f"module {cls.__module__!r} has no attribute {name!r}")`
```

I tried deleting all traces of matplotlib from my computer and fresh reinstalling it. I installed it within a conda environment as well. Nothing has worked so far.

Comment: Maybe you also have a local file called 'matplotlib.py'?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using librosa? I was getting the same error when I imported both matplotlib.pyplot and librosa.display. Removing the librosa.display import solved the issue for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I tried and it works!